# const or let in React component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Say I have a React component -- dumb or not -- and I want to grab something from the store and put it in a variable to make my code a bit more terse. Should I use const or let? Clearly the state will change.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. Again, I want to emphasize that myValues WILL change as user interacts with my app.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    render() {

        // Here, should I use const or let?
        const myValues = this.props.someData;

        return(
            <div>

            {myValues.map(item => (
                    <SomeOtherComponent key={item.id} data={item} />
                ))}

            </div>
        );
    };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        someData: state.someValuesComingFromApi
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`const` vs `let` is mostly to do with "changing" in a code block.  It only matters in situations like this:

```
const myValues = this.props.someData;
if (*some condition*) {
  myValues = [];
}
```

In this situation you would need to use let because you are changing the value assigned to the variable `myValues`:

```
let myValues = this.props.someData;
if (*some condition*) {
  myValues = [];
}
```

If `props.someData` is changing it will trigger a re-render of the component. So const vs let does not come in to play. The entire `render` method is re-run.

So that said, I use `const` in the situations you are describing. Unless you are directly manipulating the valuable of a variable, use `const`.

Comment: i have a doubt, if we are changing the value assigned to the variable, we use : `let myValues` instead of  `const myValues`. So why not use `var myValues`? Sorry for dumb question (if it is), i am a newbie in react.

Comment: @AnishArya It is generally accepted that `var` should not be used anymore, as it can lead to surprising results if you are not careful. A variable declared as `var` has function scope, ie. is accessible inside the function in which it is declared. This can trip off developers who are used to programming languages with block scope (Java, C#, C++ etc).

A variable declared as `let` or `const` has block scope, ie. is accessible only inside the block in which it is declared. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6

Answer (score 59):

[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is a signal that the **variable won’t be reassigned**.

[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is a signal that the **variable may be reassigned**

**Additional things to ponder:**

- Use `const` by default
- Use `let` only if rebinding is needed
- `const` does not indicate that a value is ‘constant’ or immutable.

  ```
  const foo = {};
  foo.bar = 10;
  console.log(foo.bar); // --> 10
  ```

  Only the binding is immutable. ie using an assignment operator or a unary or postfix -- or ++ operator on a const variable throws a TypeError exception
- ES6 `const` and `let` are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) too. Although the identifiers has the same memory reference from compile time, they cannot be accessed before declaration in the code. (but not as we thought the declaration would be physically moved to the top in the scope) ;)

Comment: +1 for "const does not indicate that a value is ‘constant’ or immutable." - this feels weird when you're just learning react but technically makes sense

Answer (score 7):

Let me refer to ESLint rule [prefer-const](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const) it has good explanation on this matter.

The only thing I can add:

prefer to start all variables with `const` *if you're not sure*

even if you mutate it later, the debugger will inform you

Answer (score 4):

- const

  is short for contant, which indicates the variable’s value won’t change.
- let

  is the opposite, meaning that the variable’s value will change
- var

  is just neutral between the two.

Comment: `var` is not "just neutral between the two", it is about the variable's scope (function level rather than block level).